# Affinity based cache listeners

Tags: gridgain

Is there a way to set up cache listneners such that the listners run on the same node where the cache entry has been inserted.

I want to run some processing on the grid for every cache entry that is `put` into the data cache. For performance, I want to run this processing on the same node where the entry exists. Whats the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subscribe a cache event listener in GridGain, then it will be executed exactly on the node where the event happened. Take a look at [CacheEventsExample](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/CacheEventsExample.java) on Github or in GridGain distro.

Here is code taken from CacheEventsExaple which subscribes optional local and remote listener for specific cache events:

```
GridFuture<UUID> fut = g.forCache(CACHE_NAME).events().remoteListen(locLsnr, rmtLsnr,
    EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT, EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ, EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED);

// Wait until event listeners are subscribed on all nodes.
fut.get();
```

Note that for event notifications to work, they must be enabled in configuration, either from code or in XML configuration file. Here is XML snippet:

```
<property name="includeEventTypes">
    <util:constant static-field="org.gridgain.grid.events.GridEventType.EVTS_CACHE"/>
</property>
```

To ignore events on backup nodes, you can have this logic in your remote listener

```
GridNode node = cache.affinity.mapPartitionToNode(event.partition());

// If we are on primary node.
if (node.isLocal())
   // Process event.
```

I also recommend watching [Distributed Events screencast on GridGain website](http://www.gridgain.org/platform/high-performance-computing/events/).

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. I was getting notifications on both nodes (in a two remote nodes grid), and hence the question. I finally figured that was due to backups. Setting backup=0 gave me what I wanted. But that raises the question how to get notifications only on primary. I could not see a way to filter out only primary puts in the predicate.

Comment: @aviks You can check if node is primary or backup directly in the remote listener. I have added the logic to do this at the end of my initial answer above.